# Change integer field in db table to display as string on cxgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcxgrid

I have a delphi form with a cxgrid on it, the grid is connected to a query/datasource.

If a field in the database table is an Integer, is there anyway of me displaying the integer as a string on the cxgrid column?

```
e.g. 1 = January
     2 = February
     3 = March
```

and so on.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other approach is to override `cxGrid` column `OnGetDisplayText` event. You could do something like that:

```
procedure TSomeForm.GetDisplayText(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
  ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord; var AText: string);
var
    nVal : Integer;
begin
    nVal := ARecord.Values[Sender.Index];    
    case nVal of
    1: AText := "January";
    //and so on
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is such possibility.

Put `TcxEditRepository` component next go your grid. Double click on it, you should see the empty window with "Add..." button. Click it and from the list of available components select `ImageComboBox`.

Now, you need to edit `Items` property of this combo.

[image]

After filling up all rows go to your view (`TcxGridDBTableView` or `TcxGridTableView`) and pick the column which contains integer values. This column has a property called `RepositoryItem`. If you did everything correctly you should be able to select the repository item which you've created earlier (the `ImageComboBox`). After selecting it, your column should immediately display month names instead of numbers.